# How do I use Bezier Curves in unity?

Tags: c#, javascript, unity

I have to rotate few objects on an ellepsoidal(Capsule shaped) track and at the run time speeds are assigned to the objects from the server as this is a betting game which I am developing in Unity 5 using C#.

So can I use Bezier Curves for that if yes then how do I use that?

Comment: What are you having trouble with exactly? The [Wikipedia page on Bézier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) is quite helpful, if quite mathsy.

Comment: Thanks but I have sorted out my problem...There is a plugin in Unity by the help of that I did it :)

Comment: OK. You could add that as an answer for future readers.  (It's fine to answer your own questions.)

Comment: Ohh so I can do that too....Hmmm I will...!